# Dictionary & KeyValuePair error when selecting item in listview

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am a novice in Xamarin and C#. I am trying to get the key and the value of an Item that I select in a listview.

Here is my code to get my listview, this work fine cause I get a list of items:

```
//search on the list view
private async Task SearchMyFriendAsync(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string keyword = SearchFriend.Text;
    Dictionary<string, string> words = await usermanager.GetUserList(keyword);
    FriendsListView.ItemsSource =  words;
}
```

When I select an item, I get an error; here is the code :

```
public async void OnSelectedFriendDescript(object obj, ItemTappedEventArgs args)
{
    var FriendName =  (KeyValuePair<string, string>)args.Item;
}
```

And here is the error :

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Which line exactly is throwing the exception? There’s two statements in that last method.

Comment: @mariocatch the last one

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. occurred

Comment: Ok so where’s the code to GetWordAsync?

Comment: sorry it was commented , do not take care of it , the error comes at the line "var FriendName =  (KeyValuePair<string, string>)args.Item;"

Comment: Place a breakpoint. Mouse over “args” and see if it’s null

Comment: @mariocatch     no it is not null , I can see my key and value

Comment: @mariocatch so I do not understand why I have this error

Comment: Then it’s not happening in that line. Get a screenshot of the exception and where it’s pointing to.

Comment: @mariocatch i added it

Comment: You’ll need to debug it and look at the values of the references you’re using. There’s a duplicate request that points to how to debug this type of thing. It’s very common and something you should learn.

Comment: @LeafLeafword, Are you using Item SelectedEvent or ItemtapEvent?

Comment: @SrustiThakkar it is ItemtapEvent

Comment: @SrustiThakkar I have tried Item SelectedEvent  and it works

Comment: @LeafLeafword, Great. Happy coding.

Comment: @SrustiThakkar thanks a lot !!! ^^